# Youtube API v3 - get list of all restricted countries

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In Youtube API v2 there was the section to describe in which countries video will be blocked:

```
<media:restriction type='country' relationship='deny'>
  BD BE BF...
</media:restriction>
```

How can I get the same information using new Youtube API v3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The country restriction details is in the video's contentDetails part. Try request like below.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id={YOUR_VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The above request will return a response something like this `"contentDetails":{...,"regionRestriction":{"blocked":["SG", "US", "SL"]}}` if the video has a country restriction. Its a list of all restricted countries for specific video.

Comment: thanks for your answer, by I want to get the list of all restricted countries, not only status for current one.

Comment: The above request will return a response something like this `"contentDetails":{...,"regionRestriction":{"blocked":["SG", "US", "SL"]}}` if the video has a country restriction. Its a list of all restricted countries for specific video. Sorry If I'm not understanding your requirement.